# How to correctly type generic function with two parameters that depend on the generic?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function `onEvent` as follows:

```
interface Events {
  'finished': {
    input: number;
    result: number;
  };
  'error': {
    input: number;
    error: Error;
  };
}

const onEvent = <K extends keyof Events>(eventLabel: K, eventDetails: Events[K]) => {
  if (eventLabel === 'finished') {
    console.log(eventDetails.input); // works, probably because 'input' is defined on both events.
    console.log(eventDetails.result); // error ts2339: Property 'result' does not exist...
  }
};
```

I would have expected that within the `if` clause, `eventLabel` is narrowed to `'finished'`, from which it is inferred that `eventDetails` can be narrowed to `{input: number; result: number}`, so that `eventDetails.result` is defined.

But that does not happen; the type of `eventDetails` is rather just `Events[keyof Events]`. Why is that and what can I do to get the typings right?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgM7IN4BQyyA5DKMNgBYQAmJAXPkccqAA4CuYTInAtgCNoAbhbEoEbJwA2PZHyGiWAXzHES0KAHsojZqzYgu8xcKjrWW3U1RQdF1WJUECCbSGxhkHjFm8AvMgAPADSyBAAHpAgtLgA1hAAntowaJg4AHwAFBAZYAAycMIyTKEANBH5ACIQYHDAMti2+dgA2qEAugCUyAGZBmxpuflFJX0BQWQU1HQkvYSG7p7aMhAAdDLaAOYj-rX1jdjrHNzdIsgA9JfIAO668diV7DqCxTJJyMIIcJzYKCRTmASGxcLQIOQQHQfCAvtowFQqv5juJkMtsKsNltdnl9nUGk11pJpHJzlcbtYoMgwNgAEwAZnpAE4mAAFHTsaBgT4kYmyYHIWjaKQKeERSKUMDraWqAhqAhAA)

Answer (score 0):

After some trying out, I found a solution. I cannot imagine it's the "canonical" one because it's a bit indirect, but it works:

```
const onEvent: (...args: {[k in keyof Events]: [k, Events[k]]}[keyof Events]) => void =
  (eventLabel, eventDetails) => {
    if (eventLabel === 'finished') {
      console.log(eventDetails.input); // works, probably because 'input' is defined on both events.
      console.log(eventDetails.result); // works now too
    }
};
```